# Does the solana protocol allow wallets to display WSOL and SOL collectively as just SOL?

Tags: solana-program

I have come across many people reporting the same issue. When attempting to send SOL from phantom wallet to CB exchange address, the transaction looked and behaved as if native SOL was being sent. But ended up funding the transaction w/ WSOL. Since WSOL is an SPL token they do not support WSOL, they did not credit my account. The funny thing is, despite being an unsupported asset, a search of the my assets bar for WSOL was able to produce a result for Wrapped Sol with a transaction history. Saying I either sent it off exchange or spent it. (assuming that means selling for fiat) How is that even remotely possible if it is unsupported, unless it is pulling up my native Sol transactions. Proving that it is interchangeable, everywhere except when crediting customer balance. Forget them helping you resolve this, they do not even try to explain the transaction history. Even though the WSOL has not moved from that wallet address, it seems to me they are manipulating their policy to almost ensure stuff like this happens to bolster the value of their reserves and to include these lost funds on their balance sheets- proving to regulators and any auditing party, that they are more than capable of remaining solvent. The amount of money a corporation holds also affects stock price. This should not be allowed. How would the Solana foundation feel about their decentralized blockchain getting exploited by centralized corporate interests.

Comment: Hmm wrapped sol is different from sol, it's meant as a way to allow programs designed for spl tokens to work with sol without needed to special case it and duplicate logic.

Comment: If you would be ok providing transaction or wallet addresses I'll be happy to take a look, you can email or DM me if you prefer not having them public.

Comment: Either way, I would highly recommend contacting the developers of the wallet application you used, wrapped sol is not a 1:1 equivalent to sol and sending wrapped sol without informing the user is not a good idea, and will break most applications. Wrapped sol can freely be converted back and forth to sol, the wallet just needs to add the correct instructions.